# Export mongodb collection to csv

Tags: mongodb, export-to-csv, mongoexport

I am exporting mongodb collection to csv which works fine and dumps "1000" records.

```
mongoexport --port=<id> --db=<name> --collection=<table-name> --type=csv --fields=<field-name> --out <file-name> --limit 1000
```

But I want to dump records within a specific timeframe, that is, dump all records with timestamp
that match the given timeframe. I could not find any documentation on how to do the same?

Is there a way to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [--query](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-query) option to pass query in JSON format,

```
--query '{ "Date": { "$gt": { "$date": "2021-01-02T07:00:00.000Z" }, "$lt": "2021-01-02T10:00:00.000Z" } }'
```